# Infinite scroll problems appending element multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

```
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function(){
     checkY();
    });
 $('.post').last().after('<div class="newPost" />');
    var hrefArray = [],//array global
    hrefs = $('.paging a[href*="/t"]').not('.paging a[href*="/t"] > img');
 for(var i=0;i<hrefs.length;i++) {
     var hreflink = $(hrefs[i]).attr('href');
     hrefArray.push(hreflink);
     }
    hrefArray.pop();
    var postedLast = $('.post').last().position().top + $('.post').last().outerHeight();

function checkY(){
if(hrefArray.length > 1) {
   if( $(window).scrollTop() > postedLast){
         var url = hrefArray.shift();
           $('.newPost').html('<img  class="loadingImg" src="http://i79.servimg.com/u/f79/17/83/35/07/loadin10.gif"/>');
setTimeout(function() {
     $('.loadingImg').remove();
     $('.newPost').last().load(url+" .post",function() {
     //THIS LINE BELOW IS THE PROBLEM
     $('.newPost').last().after('<div class="newPost" />');
     postedLast = $('.post').last().position().top +
                  $('.post').last().outerHeight();
  });
 },3000);
  } 
 }
}
     window.onLoad = checkY();
 });
```

The above code is a mock of the Infinite Scroll. My problem is it keeps appending that line over and over again. Is there a way to make it just append it once? I've tried nearly everything for this and its just not working what so ever. Also is there a way instead of do this

```
 $('.post').last().position().top + $('.post').last().outerHeight();
```

Since it doesn't seem to want to load in time. I want to make it so once the element is at the bottom of the screen it does the function. which is because of this- `if( $(window).scrollTop() > postedLast){` is there another way to do this? So instead of being at the top of the screen it does it function at the bottom of the screen? (visibly at the end)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/

I think you can probably leverage some good open source plugins that already do what you are trying to do without having to reinvent the wheel, or you could use this snippet from their second example (I found it simple, yet effective), that I am copy-pasting here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function()
{
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
    {
        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
        $.ajax({
        url: "loadmore.php",
        success: function(html)
        {
            if(html)
            {
                $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
            }else
            {
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
            }
        }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```